# Problem form Geometry

Tags: geometry

In the square $ABCD$ with side $AB = 2$ a straight line $MN$ is drawn perpendicular to $AC$. Denoting the distance from the vertex $A$ to the line $MN$ as $x$, express through $x$ the area $S$ of the triangle $A$MN cut off from the square by the straight line $M$N. Find the area at $x = 1$/$\sqrt{2}$ and at the $x = 2$.

Comment: There's no reason to suspect that $MN$ should cut off a triangle with $A$ as a vertex. It's possible that it will cut off a triangle with $C$ as a vertex, and leave a pentagon with $A$ as a vertex behind. It's possible that it won't cut anything off at all. Is there a picture you were given with this problem that may give more information about what's going on? If so, please upload and include it.

Comment: @CameronBuie! I dont have picture. But take AC = square root 8.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, assuming that the line $MN$ intersects the segment $AC,$ and that $0<x\le\sqrt2,$ we will have that triangle $AMN$ is a $45$-$45$-$90$ triangle. Taking $MN$ as its base, it has a height of $x$. (Why?) What is the length of its base in terms of $x$? What is its area, then?

Comment: Cameron Buie! Area of triangle of AMN = 1/2 (AL) (ML) + 1/2 (AL) (LN), where AL = x.

Comment: True, but that isn't in terms of $x$, even after you replace $AL$ with $x$. Try to follow my sequence of clues, and you should be able to get to an expression involving no letters at all, other than $x$.